# C++ Peeking at the stack for caller info

Tags: c++, debugging, stack

Is it possible to 'peek' at the stack enough to deduce, perhaps by mapping an address to the debug .map file or something, what the calling function is programmatically?

I have a function that is called from a ton of different places, and basically if possible I would like to be able to programmatically log out who called the function so that I can trace the progression of parameter values over time, and be able to connect them back to where they may be going wrong. I could add a parameter so that the caller must provide a user string or something, but I'd like to do something less intrusive if it's possible.

Comment: You could add simple stack tracing code: http://ideone.com/wkcTL  (Top part is a header, see last 40 lines for demo usage)

Answer (score 1):

GCC has features for this, such as __builtin_return_address (see http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html). They should be used only for debugging or special testing purposes and not as part of production code.

Answer (score 0):

You can [generate MiniDump files using windows API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680369%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and load them later in the debugger and if symbols are available you should be able to debug the crash and investigate values of variables.